# excel file read-only but not locked

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, ms-office, permission

I open an Excel file (Excel 2008) and it opens as read-only.  File info shows that it is not locked and my user account has Read-Write access and it's a LOCAL file.

Please advise on how to get back to editable file?

File name is `ca.xls`  so all those posts discussing `/` are not relevant.

Comment: Is it being edited by another user at the same time, or open by another process? Try rebooting to clear the lock on the file by other processes and try again.

Comment: @grgarside  I think you are on to something.  Perhaps `two instances` somehow got open - one not being visible.  Looks like there may be a bug in Excel to open two instances.

Answer (score 1):

Redo permissions and ACL's in Recovery.
Boot to Recovery. 
Open Terminal from the Utilities menu. 
Type in 'resetpassword' press return. 
Select your drive and user account. 
Hit button to reset ACL's. 
Reboot. 
Attempt to manipulate your file.

Comment: how does that fixes excel?